# Pass arguments to a server side CustomValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to be able to pass Arguments to a server side CustomValidator.

I want this because the control I want to validate is in an edit field of a grid.

code:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="numbercancelled" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter numbercancelled column"
                        HeaderText="numbercancelled" SortExpression="Numbercancelled" UniqueName="numbercancelled">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNumbercancelled" Text='<%# Eval("numbercancelled") %>'>
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbNumbercancelled" Text='<%# Bind("numbercancelled") %>'
                                MaxLength="10">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This is a required field"
                                ControlToValidate="tbNumbercancelled" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a number higher than 0"
                                ValidationExpression="^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$" ControlToValidate="tbNumbercancelled"
                                Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="NumberCancelledValidator"
                                runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="tbNumbercancelled"
                                OnServerValidate="NumberCancelledValidator_ServerValidate"
                                ></asp:CustomValidator>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to pass the ID of the currently being edited row, because how it's validated depends on the row you're editing.

In the end I came up with this:

```
CustomValidator cvalid = (CustomValidator)source;
GridEditFormItem gv = (GridEditFormItem)cvalid.NamingContainer;

int ItemIndex = ((GridEditFormItem)gv.EditFormCell.NamingContainer).ItemIndex;
var grid = InkoopDetailGridEdit;
int ID = int.Parse(((Label)((GridDataItem)grid.Items[ItemIndex]).Cells[0].FindControl("ID")).Text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get row index using following example:

```
CustomValidator cvalid = (CustomValidator)source;
GridViewRow gv = cvalid.NamingContainer;
int index = gv.RowIndex;
```

Comment: Even tough it wasn't a direct answer to my question, it did lead me to an answer.